# Pro rata holiday entitlement longer than required notice period, what is the process?

Tags: united-kingdom, notice-period

If you have no contracted notice period, the statutory notice you have to give is [at least one week](https://www.gov.uk/handing-in-your-notice/giving-notice). But if you are entitled to (for example) 25 days holiday a year and still have 19 days left pro rata, what is the standard procedure, assuming time travel is not possible? I guess that's where the "**at least** one week" comes in to play? Work one week and be paid for 19 days after that taken as holiday?

Are there any set regulations for these or is any of it discretionary and down to the company to decide? Could they make you forfeit any pro rata holiday entitlement?

Comment: You are asking for legal advice. 
please read: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @FrançoisGautier I asked a question before for similar advice (regarding the minimum notice period) and had no probems. I'm not asking for specific or personal legal advice for myself, I'm asking what the regulations are as I couldn't find them, and toadflakz kindly found them for me.

Comment: This should easily pass the "What a HR manager should know" test.

Comment: @Lyall I'm glad you can get an answer. However, this forum is meant for a certain kind of questions. Since you are asking regulations in the UK, maybe your question could be migrated to http://law.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @JamesFenwick Ah yes, if only there were an HR manager or department I could actually get any information out of... Or someone who could actually answer any of my questions in person.

Comment: @FrançoisGautier Understood - I have no problem moving the question if that's where it should have been posted, though I've done it before so not sure how just yet

Comment: @Lyall There is a test on The Workplace to determine whether a question is off topic when asking for legal advice. *Is this something a HR manager would reasonably be expected to know?* http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1861/41999, if it is not then the question is most likely off topic. Basic questions about holiday entitlement, in the context of a question tagged `United Kingdom` would defiantly pass the test.

Comment: @JamesFenwick I see - thanks, and will bear that in mind if I have any future questions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They have to pay you out.

https://www.gov.uk/holiday-entitlement-rights/taking-holiday-before-leaving-a-job

**From above linked site:**

> The only time someone can get paid in place of taking statutory leave (known as ‘payment in lieu’) is when they leave their job. Employers must pay for untaken statutory leave (even if the worker is dismissed for gross misconduct).

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, you would usually take that holiday as part of your notice. That said, ensure you leave enough time for a handover before you disappear. For example, work a month's notice, take your month of paid leave.

Of course, the law says you can quit with a week's notice and get paid the holiday if you want (see toadflakz's response), but good luck getting a reference after pulling that stunt.

Comment: Absolutely - I was asking about the legalities rather than the practical side. Personally I would feel guilty leaving my colleagues with not enough time to find a replacement (we are a small team).

Comment: @JohnHC. On the contrary, some companies *won't* approve holiday in your notice period once you've handed in your notice, to maximise handover time, and prefer to pay in lieu. It depends on the industry, length of service, etc.